# PHP how to get data from array

Tags: php, arrays

been trying to figure out the best way to do something.  I have the following

```
$inputParams = array();

if (isset($_POST["inputOne"]) && !empty($_POST["inputOne"])) {
    $inputOne = $_POST["inputOne"];
    array_push($inputParams, $inputOne);
}
if (isset($_POST["inputTwo"]) && !empty($_POST["inputTwo"])) {
    $inputTwo= $_POST["inputTwo"];
    array_push($inputParams, $inputTwo);
}

if (isset($_POST["inputThree"]) && !empty($_POST["inputThree"])) {
    $inputThree= $_POST["inputThree"];
    array_push($inputParams, $inputThree);
}
```

So, because not all the inputs are required, my array could have 1, 2 or 3 values.

I then come to the part that handles the array, at the moment I have something like

```
$this->inputOne = $inputParams[0];
$this->inputTwo = $inputParams[1];
$this->inputThree = $inputParams[2];
```

Obviously this is not a good way to do it, because if one of the inputs is empty (which they can be) then the above will throw an error.  I need to assign the values to a variable if they exist though, so what would be the best way to do this?  I was thinking a foreach loop, but then I dont know how much control I have over the value being assigned (if only inputOne and inputThree have data, will inputThree be assigned to variable 2?)

**UPDATE**

If I have

```
$this->inputOne = (!empty($inputParams[0])) ? $inputParams[0] : 'no data';
$this->inputTwo = (!empty($inputParams[1])) ? $inputParams[1] : 'no data';
$this->inputThree = (!empty($inputParams[2])) ? $inputParams[2] : 'no data';

var_dump("Input One is " . $this->email);
var_dump("Input Two is " .$this->mobNumber);
var_dump("Input Three is " .$this->storeCode);
```

And I fill in the fields inputOne and inputThree (giving the second one no data), then the output is

```
string(37) "Input One is myemail@gmail.com"
string(19) "Input Two is ABC123"
string(22) "Input Three is no data"
```

So the data from input three has been given to input two.  Is there any way to stop this happening?

Comment: Why does it need to be assigned to three different `$this->..` properties? Why not simply keep it in an array? For an unknown number of values, that's exactly what arrays are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can user `ternary operator` to check if variables are empty and assign.

Ofocurse this is for only if you know the number of elements in the array else `ARRAY` is your best friend

```
$this->inputOne = (!empty($inputParams[0])) ? $inputParams[0] : '';
$this->inputTwo = (!empty($inputParams[1])) ? $inputParams[1] : '';
$this->inputThree = (!empty($inputParams[2])) ? $inputParams[2] : '';
```

**UPDATE:**

You can loop through the `$this` object and check for properties which has value 'no data' and remove those properties.

```
foreach ($objects as $key =>  $value) {
   if($objects->key == 'no data'){
     unset($objects->key); // This will just remove that property.
   }
}
```

Comment: Give me two minutes to make an update to the op.  I like this answer, one slight problem though.

Comment: sure...whats the problem?

Comment: hi..check my update, you can loop through the properties and delete the properties which has value 'no data'

Answer (score 2):

If you have an unknown number of input values, then don't work with separate variables and fields for each, but use *arrays* all the way through:

```
<input name="input[]">
<input name="input[]">
<input name="input[]">

<?php
    if ($_POST) {
        $this->inputs = array_filter($_POST['input']);
    }
```

That's all you need. Gives you an array with as many input values as you got, with empty elements filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Just for example:

```
if (isset($_POST["inputThree"]) && !empty($_POST["inputThree"])) {
    $inputThree= $_POST["inputThree"];
}
else {
    $inputThree = 0; //or some value which you want
}
array_push($inputParams, $inputThree);
```

Comment: `isset && !empty` is redundant nonsense, use either or.

Comment: @deceze, if you can see, I just modified author's code, to reach his goal. And I voted for your answer, because it is right way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the input elements as `inputOne`, `inputTwo` and `inputThree`, pass the data as array using JSON object and parse it back here so you can put these in a loop and process this data in a more elegant way.

Refer for JSON.stringify here : 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Refer for json_decode here :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Once you have decoded it you can process it as an array like

```
$inputParams = array();
$inputElems = json_decode($_POST['input_arr']);

foreach($inputElems as $Elem)
{
    if (isset($Elem) && !empty($Elem)) {
    array_push($inputParams, $Elem);
}
```

Comment: `isset && !empty` is redundant. Also in your case, just `if ($Elem)` will do exactly the same thing. [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)